# Custom event "firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.complete" not working in Firebase Emulator

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

This is an android app that sends image files to Firebase Storage. Once in Firebase Storage the images are copied to another bucket where the resize images extension is enabled and converts the copied images to thumbnails. This is all verified and works as designed.

Next step is triggered when the complete notification is sent by the extension. However, the function does not get triggered. Here is the function:

```
const { onCustomEventPublished } = require("firebase-functions/v2/eventarc");

exports.onimageresized = onCustomEventPublished(
  "firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.complete",
  (event) => {
    console.log("event >>>>", event);
  }
);
```

Settings in storage-resize-images.env:

```
DELETE_ORIGINAL_FILE=true
DO_BACKFILL=false
FUNCTION_MEMORY=512
IMAGE_TYPE=jpeg
IMG_BUCKET="myapp-resize"
IMG_SIZES=200x200
IS_ANIMATED=false
MAKE_PUBLIC=true
RESIZED_IMAGES_PATH=
LOCATION=us-central1
ALLOWED_EVENT_TYPES=firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.complete
EVENTARC_CHANNEL=projects/${param:PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/channels/firebase
```

Here is what is sent for the custom event in the *emulator* (appears to be different from what is sent in production per looking at other's results online where "onCompletion" is "complete"):

```
eventarc...
Received custom event at channel projects/myapp/locations/us-central1/channels/firebase: {...

"type": "firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.onCompletion",...
```

Do custom events work in the Firebase Emulator?